# can anyone explain this phenomenon in neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have trained an [50, 500, 500, 5] neural network, the input layer have 50 neurons and the output layer have 5 neurons. The biases in layer2 change like this [image: layer2/biases]

why does the distribution of the bias in layer2 change so dramatic ?

(the distribution of the biases in layer1 are nearly same in every step.

can anyone explain this phenomenon？

Comment: I believe it's called color change, I could be wrong though.

Comment: emmmm...  I want to know the change of the distribution of the bias but not the color.

Comment: I've overlaid one half over the other and … while there *are* some differences, the main ones seem to be the color and the fact that left is cut off at 0.13, right goes on to 0.15. It could be just the graph, though.

Comment: This is not a programming question, you are asking about ML theory. This is more appropriate in http://stats.stackexchange.com/ but I think its ongoing research, so don't expect a definite answer.

Comment: Matias is right - also, it appears that your test and training set are the same based on this TensorBoard output, which means you’re not instrumenting your experiment correctly. It’s going to be very difficult to make progress if you don’t go back to fundamentals and get a more complete understanding. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

What you’re seeing is almost certainly overfitting. This isn’t a bug in your implementation, but rather an issue with your understanding. This 1,055 neuron multi-layer perceptron (MLP) has on the order of 6.25M weights (depending on you implementation)! That’s enough capacity to memorize almost any pattern. What you’re seeing in your histogram is the migration of your bias parameters to fit your data. It’s only occurring in the last layer, because the bias terms in the last layer alone are more than enough to memorize the data. Judging by the very clear parameter concentration, I’m guessing you’re training on a fairly small dataset. This is just what it looks like when your MLP is memorizing data points. Consult your train and validation loss vs. epoch curves to confirm this hypothesis.